# HTML/CSS Resizing 3 div with images from horizon position to vertical when screen size smaller than 800px

Tags: html, css

```css
.card {
 max-width: 800px;
 box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
 padding :8px;
}

.sectitle {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight:700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.seccontents {
  color: black;
  font-size: 19px;
  text-align: justify;
}

.seccontentscenter {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight:600;
}

.eg_img {
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   content: url(https://picsum.photos/200);
   object-fit: contain;
   display: inline-block;
}

.caption {
     display: inline-block;
     font-size:16px
}

.contain200 {
    width: 200px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.containMAX {
       width: 100%;
     display: inline-block;
}


@media all and (max-width: 800px) {
    div > div {
      width: 100% !important;
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>

<div class="card">
<div class="sectitle">section heading</div>
<div class="seccontentscenter">
<div class="containMAX">
<div style="float: left; width: 33.33%;"><br>
<div class="contain200">
<div class="eg_img"></div>
<span class="caption">CAPTION 1-1<br>CAPTION 1-2</span>
</div>
</div>
<div style="float: left; width: 33.33%;"><br>
<div class="contain200">
<div class="eg_img"></div>
<span class="caption">CAPTION 2-1<br>CAPTION 2-2</span>
</div>
</div>
<div style="float: left; width: 33.33%;"><br>
<div class="contain200">
<div class="eg_img"></div>
<span class="caption">CAPTION 3-1<br>CAPTION 3-2</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

I'm trying to resize 3 equally sized Div containing image and caption below it when screen size is smaller than 800px.

E.g.
When screen size > 800px:

Div1   Div2   Div3

When screen size <= 800px:

Div1

Div2

Div3

However this arrangement is not wanted:
When screen size <= 800px:

Div1 Div2

Div3

Please note that the position of the Div irregardless of screen size must always be centered.

Hope you all can help shade some light on this.

Very much appreciated and thank you all!

Comment: Please post your code till now sothat we can check that and progress on it.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to Stackoverflow. It seems like this question is now a good quality question, Here are some guidelines: Please **do not** ask us to do this for you without showing any efforts or any code attempts. Note that Stackoverflow is **not a free code writing service**, at least **show your efforts and attempts in making this**. Please read the [How do i ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the [What questions are suitable?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) section of Stackoverflow. Regards ~ anonymouse

Comment: hi there, thanks for taking the time to go thru my question. sorry i dont mean to offend or be rude. i actually posted this question on my smartphone while having a lunch break hence i did not attach any codes to it. The code snippet above was what my previous code looks like. It worked but somehow it caused a bleeding effect when on mobile, desktop browsers works ok but somehow when it comes to mobile chrome the bleeding effect occurs. Thanks to you guys ive managed to fixed it after trying out Nikola's suggestion and i had also modded it to display the images the way i intended. Tq! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to switch between flex and grid

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .container {
    display: grid;
   }
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" />
    <h3>content 1</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" />
    <h3>content 2</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" />
    <h3>content 3</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Nikola, thanks so much for your sharing. i've tried your code and it works like a charm! BTW how do I now make the horizontal arrangement of the images to occupy 100% of the total width of the horizontal container (max width 800px). in other words, The 3 Divs must be evenly spaced to occupy the total width of the parent container of max width 800px. Thank  you!

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution is to use breakpoints. You can set a breakpoint to fire when reaching a certain width and provide it with the CSS you want it to set.
I provided an example below for your problem. You can also check a live example here: https://jsfiddle.net/rs_san/8j1phdL6/1/

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id='1'></div>
  <div id='2'></div>
  <div id='3'></div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  div {
    float: left;
  }
}


div {
  position: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use flex for this, and use a media query to switch the flex direction at 800px.

```css
.container { display: flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center; }
.div { width: 30%; height: 100px; margin: 0 1%; border: 1px solid black; }

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .container { flex-direction: column; align-items: center; }
  .div { width: 70%; margin: 1% 0; }
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='div'></div>
  <div class='div'></div>
  <div class='div'></div>
</div>
```